# Photo Competition 2022-04-11: Claustrophobic

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Claustrophobic

Photos of enclosed spaces, or confined areas. Anything like small areas (think opposite of landscape/open spaces)

This theme was suggested by [BruceWayne](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/57637/).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129081/photo-competition-2022-03-28-claustrophibic?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on April 25, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

**Previous contest**: [2022-03-28: Famous Buildings](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128968/)
**Next contest**: [2022-04-25: Star Trail](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129205/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Squeezing through 'Spooky Canyon'**

[image: Spooky Canyon]

Grand Staircase Escalante, Utah

iPhone 6s, ISO 160, 29mm, f 2.2, 1/30s

Answer (score 4):

## Coal Chute

[image: Coal Chute]
*(Click to enlarge)*

Fashion shoot at an old coal chute down by the quarry in Knoxville, TN some time in late 2011 or early 2012.

Nikon gear, Ilford film, settings unknown.

Comment: Cool coal chute shoot.

Comment: I love a good homophone 

Answer (score 4):

**'Bottomless Pit'**

[image: 'Bottomless Pit']

Carlsbad Cavern, New Mexico

Canon EOS T3i with EF-S10-22mm, ISO3200, -0.3ev, f3.5, 1/6s

Answer (score 4):

[image: WW2 Bunker]\

Entrance to a partially flooded WW2 bunker, Thyboron, Denmark, August 2021

Motorola G10, f1.7, 1/50s, ISO 132, 4.71mm

Answer (score 3):

### **Street in Florence**

[image: Street in Florence, Italy]

iPhone X, 28mm, ISO 20, f1.8, 1/193s

May 2019. Taken in Florence, Italy. I grew up in a rural town where everything was very far apart, so the tight streets of cities have always felt a bit claustrophobic to me. You can see El Duomo in the background. I think its presence makes this shot seem even more closed off.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Tight Space in Baltimore]

My Mamiya 6 in Baltimore a couple months ago captured this tight space...and a lonely one at that.